# Stop explode after certain index

Tags: php, arrays, explode

How can I stop explode function after certain index.
For example

```
    <?php
        $test="The novel Prognosis Negative by Art Vandelay expresses protest against many different things. The story covers a great deal of time and takes the reader through many different places and events, as the author uses several different techniques to really make the reader think. By using a certain type of narrative structure, Vandelay is able to grab the reader’s attention and make the piece much more effective and meaningful, showing how everything happened";

    $result=explode(" ",$test);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

What if want to use only first 10 elements ($result[10])
How can I stop explode function once 10 elements are filled.

One way is to first trim the string upto first 10 spaces (" ")

Is there any other way, I don't want to store the remaining elements after limit anywhere (as done using positive limit parameter)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's about that third parameter of the function?

> array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )

check out the `$limit` parameter.

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

An example from the manual:

```
<?php
$str = 'one|two|three|four';

// positive limit
print_r(explode('|', $str, 2));

// negative limit (since PHP 5.1)
print_r(explode('|', $str, -1));
?>
```

The above example will output:

> Array (
>       [0] => one
>       [1] => two|three|four ) Array (
>       [0] => one
>       [1] => two
>       [2] => three )

In your case:

```
print_r(explode(" " , $test , 10));
```

According to the php manual , when you're using the `limit` parameter:

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a
>   maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of
>   string.

Therefore , you need to get rid of the last element in the array.
You can do it easily with `array_pop` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php).

```
$result = explode(" " , $test , 10);
array_pop($result);
```

Comment: Thanks... Is there a way to discard the next elements (which come after limit ) in positive limit?

Comment: Didn't get you , can you give an example?

Comment: Like in your example of positive limit 
[1] => two|three|four
I don't want to store this element (Array[1]) anywhere, this should be discarded
I want just
Array ( [0] => one )
instead of
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two|three|four )

Comment: Oh , ok - writing a solution for this in a second

Comment: Problem is I have very heavy string which consume lot of space, that's why I need to discard last element due to memory issues

Comment: No problem - updated my answer , check out the last part of it.

Comment: I can easily unset last element by unset(array[11])
But I was looking for a way to halt function after my limit is reached
BTW thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could [read the documentation for `explode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$result = explode(" ", $test, 10);
```