# Showing first 5 elements from my keywords list

Tags: php, html

```
<? if ($user[keywords]!="") { ?>
<div class="tpad tags font-sm">
<? foreach(explode(",",$user[keywords]) as $_ENV[tag]) { 
    echo widget("Bootstrap Theme - Tag Link","",$w[website_id],$w)." "; 
} 
?>
</div><?
```

Hi,

I am very new to php and basically just started to learn it. I am currently dealing with some code in my company new portal and would like my keywords to show but limited to 5 keywords.

Current the code works but it will show all the keywords in my list.

Can I know how to limit it to only 5 keywords? Does array_slice() help in this case?

Thanks, 
Chaven

Answer (score 1):

[array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) would help.

```
$a = 'aa,cc,bb,dd,ff,rr,hh,yy,qq,oo';

$temp = explode(',', $a);

var_dump(array_slice($temp, 0, 5));
```

**Output**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "aa"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "cc"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "bb"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "dd"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "ff"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_slice() function:

$newArray = array_slice($originalArray, 0, 5, true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $keywords = "tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,tag7,tag8,tag9,tag10";
    $explode = explode(',',$keywords);
    $exploded_Keywords = array_slice($explode, 0, 5);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($exploded_Keywords);
?>
```

**OutPut**

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag1
    [1] => tag2
    [2] => tag3
    [3] => tag4
    [4] =>  tag5
)
```

Comment: your output is what I want. But can you guide me on how to insert it in my code? I would appreciate that as I have no clue on where to add in. I tried a few method but it seems that the code is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, array_slice() will work.

Also possible to stop explode after certain index.[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936120/stop-explode-after-certain-index)

Check & Try below snippet :

```
 <?php
     if ($user[keywords]!="") 
     { 
 ?>
         <div class="tpad tags font-sm">
        <?php 
           foreach(array_pop(explode(",",$user[keywords],5)) as $_ENV[tag]) 
           { 
             echo widget("Bootstrap Theme - Tag Link","",$w[website_id],$w)." "; 
           } 
         ?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Param, this code does work. After I apply this, all the keywords that were showing before are not showing.